# How to visualize distances?

Tags: data-visualization

I have a list of cities and the distance between each city.

```
A -> B: 3km
A -> C: 5km
A -> D: 1km
B -> C: 1km
B -> D: 2km
C -> D: 5km
```

I would like to draw a graph where all cities are shown as points while the distances between the points are as near at the provided distances as possible. I am thinking of an algorithm that draws the points in space and tries to iteratively move the objects closer to the distance.

How can I accomplice that in Python?

Comment: Consider multidimensional scaling if the distance matrix is square symmetric. For rectangular matrix (bipartite graph) consider multidimensional unfolding or correspondence analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic example for when multi-dimensional scaling (MDS) is appropriate. MDS maps points, for which dissimilarities are given, to a Cartesian space of a chosen dimension (in your case, two dimensions). MDS is available in scikit-learn.

Comment: Thanks, works as charms!